# Cannot debug NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm trying to debug my NodeJS application (v10.4.0), using the command:

```
node --inspect-brk index.js
```

What I get trying to connect to chrome://inspect page for my application is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\path\to\my\app\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check which is your entry point, as you mentioned you are trying to debug with index.js but if does not exist then it shows the cannot find module error.

Comment: If I launch that script without errors on the prompt, it must exist. I have errors only when I open the chrome://inspect related page

Comment: when you open the chrome page, can you show me your logs which appear on the terminal? also if the file does not exist it will throw the error only when you try to debug it.

Comment: the one I wrote in the question. The file exists for sure because is the one I'm launching in prompt